# Is Drizzt an NPC in Storm King's Thunder?

Tags: dnd-5e, npc, storm-kings-thunder

In episode 34 of the Dice, Camera, Action! D&D stream, the legendary elf Drizzt makes an appearance. Is this a custom plotline that Chris Perkins added, or is the drow really one of the NPCs that players can interact with in the hardcover campaign?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### No

Drizzt does not appear in the campaign, but one of his companions (Harshnag, page 118-120) does appear as an allied NPC. 
And there's nothing stopping a DM that wants to add the legendary dark elf ranger to the campaign - besides a lack of official stats in Storm King's Thunder.

Answer (score 6):

Drizzt is not in *Storm King's Thunder*.  An electronic search returns no hits for his name within SKT, and a manual inspection of *Appendix D: Special NPCs* does not find any reference to him.